# Javascript replacement of the characters . with ,

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a simple replacement in a javascript form.

The form is submitting invoicenumber and amount to external payment gateway. The problem is the payment gateway doesn't accept , (comma) as seperator between the integer and fraction parts (ie. dollar,cent) but only (dollar.cent).

I want to make sure it accepts both characters . (dot) AND , (comma) so customer can use both and the form will just send . to external server.

UPDATE:

This is current javascript code:

`

```
    function startPayment() {
        var objForm = document.getElementById("ePay");

        if (objForm.merchantnumber.value.length < 7) {
            alert("Please enter your merchant!");
            return false;
        }

        paymentwindow = new PaymentWindow({

            'windowstate': 1,

            'paymentcollection': 1,

            'language': 1,

            'merchantnumber': objForm.merchantnumber.value,

            'amount': objForm.amount.value * "100",

            'currency': "208",

            'orderid': objForm.orderid.value,

        });

        paymentwindow.open();
    }



    function init() {
        var sURL = String(window.location);
        var arrURL = sURL.split("/");
        var sAcceptURL = "";
        var objForm = document.getElementById("ePay");
        var n;

        for (n = 0; n < arrURL.length - 1; n++)
            sAcceptURL += arrURL[n] + "/";

        objForm.cancelurl.value = sURL;
        objForm.accepturl.value = sAcceptURL + "accept.html";
    }

</script>`
```

This is the HTML code:

```
<tr>
<td>Amount:</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="amount" value="" style="width: 200px;" />
</td>
<td>
Amount to pay
</td>
```

Comment: Please include the tag for whatever script you are using, because this clearly is more than just vanilla javascript.

Comment: Don't forget that you have to check on the server's side either way.

Comment: `<form onsubmit="this.amount.value = this.amount.value.replace(/,/g, '.')">`

Comment: @Daedalus What makes you say that?

Comment: @iamnotmaynard This line: `paymentwindow = new PaymentWindow({`.  Unless that is a custom object..  and I'm pretty sure that isn't in js's normal list of in-built objects.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this would be either to replace the ',' with a '.' if that's what you're looking to do:

`amount.replace(/,/g, '.');`

What this line will do is use RegExp to find the occurrence of ',' and replace it with '.'. However, because you are creating a secure form to the back end, some recommended practices are to parse it at the back end first and confirm that there is no trace of things like SQL injection and make sure all input is valid. For example, if you are only looking to accept numbers and '.' in your input, I would use:

```
var rxCheck = /[0-9\.]*/g;
if (!rxCheck.test(amount)) {
    // TODO: .. code if the input is invalid ..
}
```

Good luck in your search!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
objForm.amount.value.split(",").join(".");
```

Or this:

```
objForm.amount.value.replace( /,/g, "." )
```

**Beware:** if your code is going to run in more cultures, you should handle this another way.